# Jetpack Compose - ModalBottomSheet comes up with soft keyboard

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with ModalBottomSheet and it's on my work computer so I can't record it to you right now. So basically, after I give focus to one of my TextFields, my keyboard comes up and pushes all the content upwards so I can see the TextField that I'm writing to. When I'm hiding my keyboard I can see that my ModalBottomSheet hides too, but I never set it to come up.

So if you are familiar with this bug, please let me know your solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

My coworker, so he inserted a boolean that checks if keyboard is up or not and if it is, dont put ap modal bottom sheet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method until this problem is fixed with an additional update.

You can use `LaunchedEffect` for this. Here is an example for you.

The important thing here is to disable the `ModalBottomSheetDialog` when the keyboard is opened and re-enable it half a second after the keyboard is closed.

You can trigger the required function by assigning a value to this variable when the keyboard is turned on, and then changing and checking this value when the keyboard is closed.

```
/*Change this value to "keyboard_on" when the keyboard is turned on and "keyboard_off" when the keyboard is closed again. You can give different names for different usage areas. That's why we're using a string, not a Boolean.*/
    
var taskCodeValue = remember { mutableStateOf("keyboard_off") }
    
var sheetOpener by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    
if (taskCodeValue.value == "keyboard_off"){
     LaunchedEffect(taskCodeValue.value == "keyboard_off"){
          delay(500)
          sheetOpener = true
     }

}else {
     sheetOpener = false
}
    
/*
By adding the Scaffold, which includes ModalBottomSheet and other compose 
elements, into a box, we enable them to work independently of each other.
*/
    
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    
    Scaffold(
       content = {}
    )
    
    if (sheetOpener){
       ModalBottomSheetLayout(
            sheetState = sheetState,
            sheetContent = {}
       ) {}
    }
}
```